# How to convert object into arrays for giving input of variable size images to cnn model in keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I have 271 images with all different sizes i want them to give my cnn model. Let's first take case of when i resize them all to 50*50 and i am using following code to give them to my cnn model:

```
data_path = "/home/nd/data1/"
data_dir_list = os.listdir(data_path)
img_data_list=[]

    for dataset in data_dir_list:
        img_list=os.listdir(data_path+'/'+ dataset)
        print ('Loaded the images of dataset-'+'{}\n'.format(dataset))
        for img in img_list:
            input_img=cv2.imread(data_path + '/'+ dataset + '/'+ img,0)
            img_data_list.append(input_img)

    img_data = np.array(img_data_list)
    img_data = img_data.astype('float32')
    img_data /= 255
    if num_channel==1:
        if K.image_dim_ordering()=='th':
            img_data= np.expand_dims(img_data, axis=1) 
        else:
            img_data= np.expand_dims(img_data, axis=4) 
    else:
        if K.image_dim_ordering()=='th':
            img_data=np.rollaxis(img_data,3,1)
```

That make `img_data=(271,50,50,1) of float32 type` and then finally i use `model.fit(img_data, y)`. but when i feed different size images (same in number 271) then above code (i have commented `img_data = img_data.astype('float32')` because otherwise it gives `ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.`)  make img_data as `object = (271,)` (nd array object of numpy module) and then using `mode.fit` gives me error `ValueError: Error when checking input: expected conv2d_10_input to have 4 dimensions, but got array with shape (271, 1)` (here i am not giving other details of my full code as problem is in data feeding)

Answer (score 1):

Your `img_data_list` contains images of different sizes, which makes it impossible to turn it into a `np array`. This is where the first error comes from. It is not possible to provide images of varying shapes in batches to the input of a convolutional network.

Comment: can you suggest any other deep learning libraries which can support feeding of variable size images

Comment: It should be possible, if you feed your images one by one (batch size 1). You have to make sure in that case that the actual architecture is not influenced by the varying size of the images, which will require modifications to your network. In a typical convolutional architecture, the number of output features after convolutions depends on the image input size. So it's not just a matter of picking another library

Comment: ok got your point. And my architecture is cable to handle size variation after convolution process (i make use of GlobalAvgPooling). May you please help in code, how to feed images one by one, I changed batch size =1. but how to feed image one by one i donot know

Comment: You can transform your current for loop (`for img in img_list`) into a generator that yields images one at a time. Then you train the network with `fit_generator()` instead of with `fit()`. This way, you directly feed the images one by one to the network instead of collecting them in a `np array` first (which is not possible because of the varying sizes). For some boilerplate code on how to train an CNN with a generator, you can look [here](https://github.com/sdcubber/Keras-Sequence-boilerplate/blob/master/Keras-Sequence.ipynb).

Comment: Thnx. I will try and let you know